# Dspace Production - Implantation

Tags: performance, deployment, hardware, web-deployment, dspace

I want to deploy a portal,

which has 50,000 simultaneous user connections,

Can you give me this information of how to set up a server?

What are the hardware requirements necessary to deploy?

there is some Dspace documentation on the subject of deployment / requirements?

If anyone can help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace
it has all the information you need